# how to read and edit existing pptx using Docx4j?

Tags: java, docx4j

I am using the following code to iterate over existing pptx, but how can I edit (replace text or image) in specific slide.

[Example in documentation](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/pptx4j/org/pptx4j/samples/SlideInfo.javahttp://)

```
    String inputfilepath = "C:/tmp/template.pptx";

            PresentationMLPackage presentationMLPackage = 
                (PresentationMLPackage)OpcPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));

        for (int i=0 ; i<presentationMLPackage.getMainPresentationPart().getSlideCount(); i++) {

            SlidePart slidePart = presentationMLPackage.getMainPresentationPart().getSlide(i);

            SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutPart = slidePart.getSlideLayoutPart();

            //System.out.println(slp.getSourceRelationships().get(0).getTarget());
            System.out.println(slidePart.getPartName().getName());

            String layoutName = slideLayoutPart.getJaxbElement().getCSld().getName(); 

            System.out.println("layout: " + slideLayoutPart.getPartName().getName() + " with cSld/@name='" + layoutName + "'");

            System.out.println("Master: " + slideLayoutPart.getSlideMasterPart().getPartName().getName());

}
```

Comment: To replace text, you change the content in the relevant SlidePart.  If you look at the XML in a SlidePart, you'll see an image is stored in a separate object, and referenced via a relationship.  So to replace an image, you can alter the contents of the referenced object.  A good way to start is to upload your pptx to the docx4j webapp, which helps you to inspect its contents and generate code.

Comment: See also the various samples at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/src/samples/pptx4j/org/pptx4j/samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done many researches on office files like docx,xlsx,ppt
I would like to suggest you one thing
Once you open your file with zip/rar you will find its internal file structure

```
Files 

_rels
docProps
ppt
```

[Content_types].xml
these folders contain files are usually xml 
PPt and move to slides inside slide 
there will be xml files names slide1..2..3.etc
these files have every text you type in your ppt.
Replace Xml file with your content
using the java coding and place it back into zip file.

Thats it.
Its working 100% i have implemented it many times.

```
**summary:**

In java code just try this
1.Rename your file extension from pptx to zip
2.extract path ppt\slides\[yourslide].xml
3.do your content replacement for the extracted xml file.
4.Place it back into zip 
5.rename the file extension to pptx
```

That is it enjoy!!!

regards,
Kishan.c.s