# How to append data with FileOutputStream to a pptx file?

Tags: java, powerpoint, fileoutputstream

I am trying to append content to a `pptx` file using the below code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile,true);
InputStream is = conn.openDataInputStream();
int length = 4096;
byte[] byteArray = new byte[length];

while (true) {

    int count = is.read(byteArray);
    if (count ==-1) {
        break;
    }
    fos.write(byteArray, 0, count);

}
```

But it's not getting appended. Am I forgetting to add something?

Does the above appending method only apply for `txt` files?

EDIT:

I got the issue fixed. It was actually the File explorer from which i was checking the file size was not getting refreshed!
The above code did work for appending downloaded data to 'pptx' file.
Used   'RandomAccessFile' instead of 'FileOutputStream' (but both seems to be working fine)

Thanks for the support :)

Comment: This will indeed append the downloaded bytes to the file, and is a correct way to append the downloaded bytes to the file, but is appending the downloaded bytes to the file really the thing you want to do?

Comment: *"Am I missing [...] something?"* Yes, you're entirely missing what the [format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) of a PPTX file is. It is not a stream of byte you can just append to, it is a complex file format. It is actually a ZIP file consisting of a combination of XML and BINARY files.

Comment: Initial download of the document using the above code is working fine. Am able to view the pptx file once download is complete. But when am trying to append, it is getting failed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40787407/6032482 ... this is what pptx is

Comment: You need to use POI library to deal with pptx it is not a simple text file.

Comment: I am trying to resume an interrupted download of pptx file. In that case do I need to download the entire contents again as I am not sure up to what data the download was success or will it be possible to resume from where it got interrupted?

Comment: If you are resuming an interrupted download then you should be able to resume from where it got interrupted.

Comment: You are forgetting to close the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue fixed. It was actually the File explorer from which i was checking the file size was not getting refreshed! The above code did work for appending downloaded data to 'pptx' file. Used 'RandomAccessFile' instead of 'FileOutputStream' (but both seems to be working fine)

Thanks for the support :)